# Unable to run UAP app without installing vc_redist.64

Tags: uwp, packaging, c++-winrt, vcredist

I'm using VS 2022, and have a UWP app that references a WinRT project.
I'm trying to create a package so I can sideload it onto a separate computer to test that the installer includes everything required.

I've included references to Microsoft.VCLibs and Visual C++ 2015-2019 UWP Desktop Runtime for native apps in the .csproj of the UWP project, and they show up in the "dependencies" folder when the package gets created. However, my app does not work correctly when installed. It works if I install VC_redist.64 manually (separately).

I'm not sure what I've done wrongly? Is there a way to include the VC_redist libraries in a package for sideload?

Comment: I'm guessing that's a dependency of the Windows Runtime component you're referencing. If it is then you won't be able to successfully get your UWP application WACK certified.

Comment: For now I don’t need to upload it to the store, so don’t really need it WACK certified…. But you’re right…. 

The WinRT project I’m referencing is what uses the vs_redist. Is this not something doable? What solution can I use to make an installer for a UWP app that references a WinRT project using vs_redist?

Answer (score 0):

What does the generated `.appxmanifest` file look like for your UWP? Generally, the installation of the VC++ Runtime is managed by the Microsoft Store based on the appxmanifest.

Note that there is a specific package you can use for installing the runtime the way the Store does offline. See [UWPDesktop Downloadable AppX Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102159).

**UPDATE:** The root problem here seems to be that the WinRT library is built with the VS 2022 toolset, but the UWP application is using VS 2019. That means the CRT requirement injected into the UWP application is not fully up to date.  It is true that VS 2015 Update 3 - VS 2022 offers "forward binary compatibility", but that only works if the distributed binary is the *newest* one.

Comment: The final package includes the UWP desktop package in the dependencies folder, so it should be included as part of the installation…. But the the app only works if I manually install the separately downloaded “vc_redist”… so it doesn’t look like the WinRT module is able to use the vc runtimes bundled with UWPDesktop?

Comment: When you build the WinRT project, are you sure it's set to use the UWP CRT? Does it use the same VC version and PlatformToolset?

Comment: how can I check this? Where in properties can I find the UWP CRT / VC version / Platform toolset? They target the same platform as far as I can tell (from the Properties -> General tab) 

For the UWP app the app manifest has "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" MinVersion="14.0.30704.0" and "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.24217.0" 

The vc_redist I install separately is version 14.32.31332.0.

I'm not sure how to make the WinRT project reference the "uwp crt"?

Comment: What "Platform Toolset" are both projects using?

Comment: The WinRT project uses platform toolset Visual Studio 2022 (v143), but I wasn't able to find this setting for the UWP project.

Comment: You should make sure your UWP project is using at least as new a toolset as your library. I would suggest running the Visual Studio Installer again and making sure you have the component "C++ Universal Windows Platform tools (v143)" installed.

Comment: I re-ran the VS Installer, it shows that component is already installed...

Comment: I checked the UWP project's csproj file - it has a ToolsVersion of 15.0 - is this what you meant by the toolset? If it's ToolsVersion, then both the csproj (UWP) and vcproj (WinRT) projects use 15.0....

Comment: Currently my WinRT component doesn't seem to be packaged together with the UWP app, resulting in me having to install it separately, so it goes into C:\Program Files\... Whereas the UWP app gets installed into some special location that Apps get installed to..... I'm wondering if this is why the WinRT won't pick up the UWP version of the VC redist....? (The UWP does have the WinRT component as a reference though... Is there a way to package the WinRT component together with the UWP app? I'm probably missing a step here somewhere?)